# Ocultar Menu Navigation Drawer ao escolher item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Gostaria de uma ajuda de como posso fazer ao clicar no item do Nvaigation Drawer ir para o Fragment especifico, sendo que nesse Fragment nao quero que fique disponivel o Navigation Drawer pra o usuário.

Menu Navigation Drawer do App Mercado Livre

[image]

Ao clicar em um item do menu o mesmo nao aparece mais o menu, só se voltar primeiro

[image]

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao [pt.so], você já tentou fazer algo? Já tem algum código? Aconselho dar uma olhada nesse link: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), depois você pode conhecer um pouco mais do SOpt fazendo um [tour]

Comment: Olá Mateus obrigado pela atenção, o exemplo foi passado nas imagem da publicação, eu ja tenho o Navigation Drawer pronto. apenas quando eu chamo o Fragment eu quero que o Drawer nao apareça apenas se eu voltar pra a Activity Principal onde tem o Menu... 
abaixo exemplo de como eu chamo o Fragment..

`ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: Ainda não estou muito familiarizado com *Fragments*, você pode tentar dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), veja se ele te ajuda em algo

Comment: Certo meu projeto fiz baseado nesse exemplo mesmo.. a duvida é apenas como eu disse após chamar o Fragment ficar na tela apenas esse fragment e nao aparecer o Navigation Drawer

Comment: @Leonardo, coloque esse código na pergunta também, fazendo assim fica melhor para outras pessoas entenderem sua situação.

Comment: Leonardo, não é só chamar o método `closeDrawer` passando o seu `ListView` dentro do `onItemClick` do `Listener` do `ListView`? Seria legal seguir a sugestão do Luídne e colocar o código que você faz para configurar o seu `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Para esconder o menu após o usuário selecionar um item basta você fazer o seguinte código no click do item:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lst);
```

Um exemplo de como fazer todo o processo:

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView lst;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayoutAdapter  drawerLayoutAdapter;
```

No onCreate da sua Activity faça o seguinte código:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
              super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon( new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

E no click do item :   `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lst);`

Answer (score 0):

Poderia desativar a ActionBar do `Fragment` específico. Outra coisa que eu encontrei qu e seria, de certa forma, um jeito de não aparecer o `Drawer`: a solução é utilizar o `setVisible` e chamar um método para restaurar a `ActionBar`.